# Purple Screen after trying to boot into Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot

I flashed the Ubuntu iso onto my USB, booted into it and now a purple screen is happening.  Picture linked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mteYa.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: That's the boot screen. Unless it freezes on it, I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the boot process is stuck at some point. Potential culprits are often graphic drivers. Maybe you can use the recovery mode (if that's available when booting from USB).
Alternatively, press the Esc-key to see what is going on in the background. Or you can try CTRL-ALT-T to open a terminal for obtaining further information.